# SimpleModal JQuery HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplemodal

I am using the simple modal JQuery plug in to display a single dialogue box on my HTML website. It works well but now I would like to display two or more separate dialogue boxes on the same page.

Is this possible?

I am using the code from the demo download with the JQuery calls and css file.

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='content'>
<div id='basic-modal'>
<a href='#' class='basic'><img src="images/BlueButtonAccess.png" alt="Access Atatement" id="Image4" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image4','','images/BlueButtonAccess2.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" /></a></div>           
<!-- modal content -->
<div id="basic-modal-content">
<div id="simplemodal-header">
<h3>Hill House Access Statement </h3>
</div>          
<div id="iframebox"><iframe src="Access Statement iframe.htm" style="background-color: #3D4049;"width="780" height="476" align="left" frameborder="no" marginheight="0px" scrolling="vertical" ></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<!-- preload the images -->
<div style='display:none'>
<img src='images/CloseButton2.png' alt='' id="Image6" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Image6','','images/CloseButton.png',1)" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" />            
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the dialog boxes simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Bootstrap. They provide this functionality (without a lot of work). Here is the direct link to what you are talking about - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals